# Checking duplicate while inserting in SQLite

Tags: python, windows, sqlite, pysqlite

I am trying to insert a data into SQLite database using Python.

```
INSERT INTO DATA_TABLE(UID,LABEL) VALUES (NULL, "UK")  
    WHERE "UK" NOT EXISTS IN (SELECT LABEL FROM DATA_TABLE);
```

This query is dynamically generated from Python and I am checking whether the date is already exist in the table before inserting and its not working in SQLite database. 
Getting this `near "WHERE": syntax error` error.

Am I doing something wrong ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that `INSERT` doesn't have a `WHERE` clause ([the documentation doesn't mention any](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html)). What you can do:

- create a unique index on `LABEL`
- use `INSERT OR FAIL`
- if that triggers an error, the row already exists.

Comment: Yes, I didn't aware of that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

It is giving you a syntax error because it is not [allowed syntax](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html). From your example I presume the schema is probably:

```
create table data_table (uid integer primary key autoincrement.
     label string);
```

in which case `primary key` implies `unique`. But, since you allow auto-generation of `uid` then you don't care what it's value is, you just don't want duplicate `label`s in which case you actually care that `label` be unique so tell it so:

```
create table data_table (uid integer primary key autoincrement,
     label string unique on conflict fail);
```

which then works as expected:

```
sqlite> insert into data_table (label) values ("uk");
sqlite> insert into data_table (label) values ("uk");
Error: column label is not unique
sqlite> select * from data_table;
1|uk
```

Incidentally, if the names `data_table`, `uid`, and `label` aren't example names for the purposes of this question then you should use more meaningful names as these are horribly uninformative.

Comment: Thanks @msw , thats true. names are just example's , I am using label as a unique.

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO DATA_TABLE(UID,LABEL) VALUES (NULL, "UK")  
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM DATA_TABLE WHERE LABEL="UK");
```

you can use this instead of INSERT OR FAIL.